# Post Type Label Name

Tags: posts, customization

i've just created a new post type. It's name is Academias so the first menu option is Academias as well. But I would like to change it to something like See All Academias (just an example), is that possible?

Comment: Where specifically do you want to see the phrase *"See All Academias?"*

Comment: Mike, at the Main menu text, where you have the button that shows the drop down options. But I think toscho answer solves the problem

Comment: Yes, @toscho answered it, great! *(I was just doing my part to coach on how to write questions that require you to answer fewer follow up questions!)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) takes an argument `'labels'`. This is an array, one of the possible keys is named … tada! … `'menu_name'`.

#### Sample code

```
register_post_type(
    'academias'
,   array (
        'can_export'          => TRUE
    ,   'exclude_from_search' => FALSE
    ,   'has_archive'         => TRUE
    ,   'hierarchical'        => TRUE
    ,   'label'               => 'Academias'
    ,   'labels'              => array ( 'menu_name' => 'See All Academias' )
    ,   'menu_position'       => 5
    ,   'public'              => TRUE
    ,   'publicly_queryable'  => TRUE
    ,   'query_var'           => 'academias'
    ,   'rewrite'             => array ( 'slug' => 'academias' )
    ,   'show_ui'             => TRUE
    ,   'show_in_menu'        => TRUE
    ,   'show_in_nav_menus'   => TRUE
    ,   'supports'            => array ( 'editor', 'title' )
    )
);
```

#### Update

Now, that I’ve understood your question better, there seems to be only one way to accomplish what you want: hook into `attribute_escape`.

#### Test Plugin

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: *WPSE13210
*/
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;

add_action( 'init', 'register_academia' );

/**
 * Registers te post type academias
 *
 * @return void
 */
function register_academia()
{
    register_post_type(
        'academias'
    ,   array (
            'can_export'          => TRUE
        ,   'exclude_from_search' => FALSE
        ,   'has_archive'         => TRUE
        ,   'hierarchical'        => TRUE
        ,   'label'               => 'Academias'
        ,   'labels'              => array (
                'menu_name' => 'See All Academias'
            ,   'name' => 'Academias'
            )
        ,   'menu_position'       => 5
        ,   'public'              => TRUE
        ,   'publicly_queryable'  => TRUE
        ,   'query_var'           => 'academias'
        ,   'rewrite'             => array ( 'slug' => 'academias' )
        ,   'show_ui'             => TRUE
        ,   'show_in_menu'        => TRUE
        ,   'show_in_nav_menus'   => TRUE
        ,   'supports'            => array ( 'editor', 'title' )
        )
    );
}

add_filter( 'attribute_escape', 'rename_second_menu_name', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Renames the first occurence of 'See All Academias' to 'Academias'
 * and deactivates itself then.
 * @param $safe_text
 * @param $text
 */
function rename_second_menu_name( $safe_text, $text )
{
    if ( 'See All Academias' !== $text )
    {
        return $safe_text;
    }

    // We are on the main menu item now. The filter is not needed anymore.
    remove_filter( 'attribute_escape', 'rename_second_menu_name' );

    return 'Academias';
```

}

Not very elegant, but at least a solution …

### Update 12.05.2010

In [ticket 17378](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17378) a new parameter `all_items` was proposed. That should work much better, once it’s part of the core …

Comment: Hi toscho, thanks for your asnwer, but that`s not exactly what I want. When I set an value for menu_name it changes the menu page name and also the sub menu page name. I have that: Academias -> Academias, Add New and I want Academias -> See all Academias, Add new

Comment: @Vitor Argos Oh, now I understand. I’ve added some code.

Comment: Hey toscho, ok I applied it to my functions.php and I have a little problem. When the function actually works my admin dashboard gets a broken style. Also i read a little about this filter and it`s deprecated, wouldn`t it be a problem? (I`m new to wordpress programming hehe)

Comment: @Vitor Argos the function with the same name is deprecated, not the filter. Did you copy the last `}`? For no obvious reason the highlighter takes it out of the code block. In my tests the plugin worked just fine. Use the code from https://gist.github.com/889394

Comment: Oh, thanks toscho. I tried to edit the code but i did a stupid mistake thats why it was not working. Everything is fine now, thanks a lot for you help!